# Subnetting how many networks can be contained

Tags: subnet

Ok so I have a submitting question I know the answer too but don't know why it is the right answer:

How many /16 networks can be contained in a /8 network? The answer is 2^(8), but why? What math is done to figure that out?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IPv4 address is 32 bits. If the network takes 8 bits, that leaves 24 bits for subnets and addresses.  Your subnet size is 16 bits (for the hosts).  That leaves 8 bits for the number of subnets. That is why it is 2^8 for the number of subnets, and 2^16 for the number of addresses.

```
11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000
Network- Subnet-- Addresses--------
```